# App downloaded from cousin's Apple ID is greyed out and cannot delete it from iTunes

Tags: ios, ipad

My cousin downloaded an app for me on my iPad Air while using his Apple ID. I signed out of it, and logged into mine. I updated my device to iOS 10 after I had to temporarily delete apps due to low storage.

Bloons TD 5 was one of them, and after going to the home screen, it was greyed out and it said Waiting. I tried to delete it, but there was no X. By the way, my cousin never gives his Apple ID password to anyone, since it is his mom's Apple ID.

Apparently, I pressed the power button, and pressed it again. I went to the home screen, and it was greyed, but the name was showing. The X showed this time, and I pressed delete, however, it was still there. I tried going on my computer and deleting it from iTunes, but none of my apps were showing and iTunes wasn't able to check for updates, since it was looping.

I tried rebooting, but it changed to Waiting. I cannot reset because my parents put a restrictions passcode on my iPad Air even though I'm like 19. They won't tell me no matter what. It doesn't show in storage, and there isn't anyway of getting my cousin's Apple ID password, especially since he lives far away.

Comment: Did you try actually connecting your phone to iTunes?

Comment: Yes, I have, and when iOS 10.02 came out, I updated and the app was still there. When I tried to restore, it said there weren't any resources or something of that sort. Changing the date back makes the app name change to Waiting..., but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

**Update your Apple ID and password on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac, and PC.
iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.**

1. Go to Settings > iTunes & App Store.
2. If you're signed out, enter your updated Apple ID and password.
3. If you're signed in with your previous Apple ID, tap your Apple ID,
       then tap Sign Out.
4. Then enter your updated Apple ID and password.

**Mac with OS X Mountain Lion or later, or Windows PC**

1. Go to the [Apple Online Store](http://store.apple.com/).
2. Click [image] , then click View
   Account.
3. In the Account Settings section, click "Update your Apple ID email
   address and password."
4. Enter your updated Apple ID and password.